How to get Data Object field value in task?
I have Data Object named 'ProcessDataObject'. This object has fields 'ammount', 'departament'.
Process  Form base on this data object (so in form I have fields 'ammount', 'departament').
In 'Process Data' I have 'Process Variables':
ProcessDataObject (name) -  ProcessDataObject [com.xx.xxxx] (data type)
departament (name) - String (data type)

How to get 'departament' field value I put in Form starting the process?
In User Task in 'Data Inputs and Assignments' I tried everything like 'ProcessDataObject.departament':

But it does not work - I cannot get 'departament' name in the task or other project object.

I think your use case can be achieved using kcontext.getVariable() construct. You can see it in action in existing codebase [1].
So it is a java code you can put into a Task definition - On Exit Action. Then, this code will be executed once the task is completed. As the code can access a process variable, you should be able to access ProcessDataObject.department and eventually store it into a new variable using kcontext.setVariable.
[1]
https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapache%2Fincubator-kie-kogito-runtimes+kcontext.getvariable+language%3AXML&type=code

Thanks for your involvement. Since most of the process diagrams are as follow, START => TASK [form] => ANOTHER TASK..., there would be not much sense to getVariable on task exit (I need it in task). Anyway this variable is empty. Looks like form fields that are based on Nested Form (and Data Object fields) does not work at all - values that are entered into forms field never reach Data Object. I built trivial diagram: Start event [process form/data object fields]  => Exclusive Gateway => [condition: ProcessDataObject.department, Equals to, xx) and ProcessDataObject.department is always Null.

I decided to recreate project this time with different data object name.
I suspect that the name data object could be treated as a reserved variable name. And this time, with a unique name for the data object... it worked. I took the 'department' variable from the data object using JavaScript (On Entry Action) - in Task.
I wanted to regenerate the problem again but despite deleting that data object when starting a new process there is an error... this old data object is somewhere in memory/on disk. I give up. So 99% sure something was wrong with the name 'ProcessDataObject'.
JBPM is a very rickety system full of bugs and errors.
